# flash as3 zooming in (scaling up) to a specific point within a clip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to scale a container/parent movie clip up so that I effectively zoom in to a point referenced by one of its children. I've figured out how to use globalToLocal to get that point at the center of the stage, but the problem is the registration point for the container clip is (and needs to stay) at the upper left, so when I scale the container clip up, the point does not stay in the center of the screen. Here's my code:

//REVISED:

```
var stageCenter = new Point(int(stage.stageWidth/2),int(stage.stageHeight)/2);
    var parPointLocal = parRef.globalToLocal(stageCenter);
    TweenMax.to(treeClip,.5,{x:parPointLocal.x,y:parPointLocal.y,onComplete:doZoom});

    function doZoom():void {
        var zoomPoint = zoomToMember(treeClip,stageCenter,2);

        function zoomToMember(target:MovieClip, center:Point, scale:Number):Point {
            var m:Matrix = new Matrix();
            m.translate(-center.x, -center.y);//move the center into (0,0)
            m.scale(scale, scale);//scale relatively to (0,0) (which is where our center is now)
            m.translate(center.x, center.y);//move the center back to its original position
            return m.transformPoint(new Point());//transform (0,0) using the whole transformation matrix to calculate the destination of the upper left corner
        }

        TweenMax.to (treeClip,.5,{x:zoomPoint.x,y:zoomPoint.y,scaleX:2,scaleY:2})

    }
```

When I do this, the zoomed point ends up being somewhere around "Mabel Greer's Toy Shop" - which I imagine was the center point of the stage before the treeClip was tweened so that "Jon Anderson" would be at the center of the stage.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to calculate the destination position of the upper left corner after scaling and tween the x and y properties to it.

The most simple way is to use matrices:

```
function scale(target:MovieClip, center:Point, scale:Number):Point {
    var m:Matrix = new Matrix();
    m.translate(-center.x, -center.y);//move the center into (0,0)
    m.scale(scale, scale);//scale relatively to (0,0) (which is where our center is now)
    m.translate(center.x, center.y);//move the center back to its original position
    return m.transformPoint(new Point());//transform (0,0) using the whole transformation matrix to calculate the destination of the upper left corner
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I sort of get it (sorry) but when I implement it, it doesn't quite seem to be zooming to the right location. I've edited my description above to show the revised code. Any help you could provide would be great

Comment: Oh - also - why did you include the movie clip as a parameter of the function if the movieclip (target) is not being utilized? Should it be?

Comment: Yeah, including target isn't actually of use :) . However, if the center Point is in fact expressed in global coordinate space, then you need to do `center = target.globalToLocal(center);`, which makes the target necessary again.

Comment: awesome - thanks! Not sure I fully understand the whole matrix concept yet, but your answer definitely helped.